# How to do a -Contain -Not : String contains "Anything other than"

Tags: powershell

How can I script "Does String -contains -not _" / "Does the string contain anything other than _"?

I'm not stuck as I've found a good enough work around.  More curiosity than anything else.

Example:

```
$String = 1,1,1,2,5
$String -contains !(1)
```

This always comes up False

My solution at the moments is to remove the 1's and see if it's null like so:

```
$String2 = $String -ne 1
if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($String2)) {
    Write-Host "True"
} else {
    Write-Host "False"
}
```

Real World Example:

My script is designed to try a certain action until it works.  In this case get-msoluser.
At the end of my script I want to count any errors (and list them later) but there will always be an error listed for "get-msoluser" as it fails until it works.  So I'm trying to not include that certain error in the count.

```
$Errors = $Error.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name
if ($Errors -contains !("get-msoluser")) {
    Write-Host "There was an error I actually care about"
}
```

INSTEAD I have to do this:

```
$Errors = $Error.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name
$ErrorsICareAbout = $Errors -ne "get-msoluser"
if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($ErrorsICareAbout)) {
    Write-Host "$ErrorsICareAbout.Count"
} else {
    Write-Host "There were errors you actually cared about"
}
```

Am I missing something that's right under my nose?

Comment: Have you tried `If (!($Errors -contains ("get-msoluser")))`

Comment: Yep.  Right under my nose.  Thanks!

Comment: `-notcontains` is the operator you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use `-notcontains` or add the not operator around then entire `-contains` comparison like this:

```
If ($Errors -notcontains ("get-msoluser"))
```

or

```
If (!($Errors -contains ("get-msoluser")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than filtering out the error, try not producing an error in the first place.  To suppress errors from a particular command, you can set the error action to SilentlyContinue.

```
Write-Error 'fail' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

So in the case of retrying until Get-MsOlUser works, you could use something like

```
while($msolUser -eq $null) {
   $msolUser = Get-MsOlUser ... -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   #Wait a second before retrying.
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1   
}

#Now work with $msolUser
```

(You probably also want to put an upper limit on the number of retries)

Comment: I'm currently using this to suppress the error on the powershell screen but it still appears to make its way into the $error variable.

Retry after the second time is manual by the person running it, with a "move on" cancel popup button.